# Trying to print value of local variable before it is assigned

Tags: python

I am following along to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v07t_GEIQzI&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDeETZEOy4VdocT7TOjfSA8a&index=2). The goal is to convert the screen into gray so that the neural network has an easier time manipulating the data.

However when i run my code it says local variable `processed_img` referenced before assignment. So i put `global` in front of it and then it says that it is not defined.

How do I fix this?

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

def process_img(image):
    processed_img
    processed_img = cv2.Canny(processed_img, threshold1=200, threshold2=300)
    return processed_img

with mss.mss() as sct:
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 960, "height": 540}     # Part of the screen to capture
    new_screen = process_img(monitor)

while (True):
    last_time = time.time()
    img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))                          # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
    cv2.imshow('Window',new_screen)                               # Display the picture
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):                         #This keeps the screen displayed over time, 1 = screen's refresh rate
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with neural networks or image processing. It's a simple matter of Python syntax. I changed the title and tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to make these changes:

```
def process_img(image):
    processed_img = cv2.Canny(image, threshold1=200, threshold2=300)
    return processed_img
```